# Alternative to TypeDescriptor in Silverlight 3?

Tags: c#

Am using this code in WPF to check for properties.

```
if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
{
      //some code here...
}
```

I want to use the same logic in Silverlight 3, but there is no TypeDescriptor. Anyone knows an alternate way to do it in Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reason not to use [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) / [`Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx)?

```
PropertyInfo property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
...
```

I know they're not quite equivalent, but if you're dealing with a "normal" property it may well be close enough.